# closed subset in C[-1,1]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H = C[-1,1] $ with $(f,g)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\overline{g(t)}$. 
Let $H_0=\{f\in H: \int_{-1}^0f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt\}$

a) Prove that $H_0$ is closed subset in $H$

b) Prove that $H = H_0 + H_0^\perp$

For the first one, we can take $f_n\in H_0$ such that $f_n\to f$ and prove that $f\in H_0$. Is it enough to say that $|\int_{-1}^1f(t)dt-\int_{-1}^1f_n(t)dt|=|\int_{-1}^1(f(t)-f_n(t))dt|\le|\int_{-1}^1|f(t)-f_n(t)|dt| \to0_{n\to\infty}$?

For the second one, is it enough to prove that $H_0^\perp = {0}$ and then use theorem about orthogonal projection?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{-1}^0 f(t)\, dt = \int_0^{-1} f(t)\, dt$ or $\int_{-1}^0 f(t)\, dt = \int_0^1 f(t)\, dt$?

Comment: @Connor Harris The second one, thanks

Comment: The space is not complete so you cannot use the theorem you are quoting.

Comment: What is $X?\,\,$

Comment: @zhw. It's $H$, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part b) is false. Let us show that $H_o^{\perp} =\{0\}$. It then follows that b) cannot hold because the function $f(x)=x$ belongs to $H$ but not to $H_0+H_o^{\perp}$. To prove that $H_o^{\perp} =\{0\}$ let $h \in H_o^{\perp}$. Let $g$ be any function in $L^{2}[-1,1]$ such that $\int_{-1}^{0} g(x)\,dx =\int_0^{1} g(x) \, dx$.   There exists a sequence $\{g_n\}$ of continuous functions such that $\int_{-1}^{1} |g_n(x)-g(x)|\, dx \to 0$. Let $\phi_n(x)=g_n(x)-c_nx$ where $c_n=\int_0^{1}g_n(x) \, dx-\int_{-1}^{0}g_n(x) \, dx$. Then (it is easy to check that) $\phi_n \in H_0$ for all $n$. Hence $\int_{-1}^{1} h(x)\phi_n(x)\, dx=0$ for all $n$. This gives $$\int_{-1}^{1} h(x)g_n(x)\, dx=c_n\int_{-1}^{1} xh(x)\, dx\,\,\,\, (1).$$ Note that $c_n=\int_0^{1}g_n(x) \, dx-\int_{-1}^{0}g(x) \, dx\to \int_0^{1}g(x) \, dx-\int_{-1}^{0}g(x) \, dx=0$. Hence it follows (by letting $n \to \infty$ in (1)) that$\int_{-1}^{1} h(x)g(x)\, dx=0$. Now we have proved that $h$ is orthogonal to  the orthogonal complement of the function $\psi (x)=-1$ for $x <0$, $\psi (x)=1$ for $x >0$ in the Hilbert space $L^{2}[-1,1]$. This implies that $h=a\psi$ almost everywhere for some constant $a$. This contradicts the fact that $h$ is a continuous unless $a=0$. Hence $h=0$ and the argument is complete.

Comment: Thank you! What about part a), is it correct?

Comment: For a) you have to observe that  $\int_{-1}^0 f_n \to \int_{-1}^{0} f$ and  $\int_{0}^1 f_n \to \int_{0}^{1} f$.

Comment: It's because $\int_{a}^b f_n \to \int_{a}^{b} f$ , right? It's easy to show

Comment: @user1223 Yes, $\int |f_n-f| \to 0$ implies $\int_a^{b} f_n \to \int_a^{b} f$ for any $a<b$.

Comment: Thank you so much!